# openlayers get database informs using geoserver

Tags: openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I am using geoserver, and POSTGIS
and, I tried to Get Database informs from postgis on openlayers, So My question is:

1. Is there any way sending request sql to postgis on openlayers?
2. Or is there a geoserver api that sending request sql dialect to postgis and return results
3. Any other way to Get database informs from postgis?

Comment: What do you mean with "database informs"? You can request data from Geoserver using the WFS protocol: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

Comment: For example: database name which feature located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL View on Geoserver Side. You write you SQL request with the params you want to query like `select info from country where country = '%param%'` and then request the WMS with mergeParams where param is `&viewparams=country:[the country you want]`

Here's the link to Geoserver's doc which is pretty well explained : http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: Can I use query 'create database a' with SQL View? I think it may not

Comment: I don't know, I don't think it has to be postgis to do that, but an ajax request or everything else. I just answered your first question, i.e *Is there any way sending request sql to postgis on openlayers*